# Gridview for ICS based calendar widget

Tags: android, events, gridview, calendar, widget

I am trying to make a Calendar widget for ICS with UI similar to G0Calendar widget

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.calendarwidget&hl=en

I am referring https://nodeload.github.com/JoseGD/MonthCalendarWidget/zipball/master
which uses Textviews to show the indivaidual days. 
I wish to know if similar UI can be achieved using GridView. I need to highlight the days having some events & if user touches that day, the agenda for that day will be shown.
Any examples, links, hints are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: 12 views & still no response ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with API 11 and above.

GridView is a [Collection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections), and to work with it in a widget you should implement its adapter extending RemoteViewsService. You will also need a nested class to implement RemoteViewsFactory, witch will take care of retrieving the data to fill your GridView.

With RemoteView.setRemoteAdapter(int viewId, Intent intent), you can link your GridView layout with the adapter you just created.

Also, add this to your manifest:

```
<application>
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".Your_RemoteViewsService_Class"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
</application>
```

You can use different views layouts to highlight data in your grid and intents to call an agenda.

There is a similar example in this link: http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/src/com/example/android/stackwidget/index.html